# Resetting jQuery .one event after client side validation

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery function

```
$('#AddItem').one("click", function () {

//client side validation code
//if validation passes make an ajax call. after call returns redirect to another page

$(this).click(function () { return false; });

}
```

If validation fails, the function fires only once. Is there a way to re-register or re-bind the function after validation fails?

I added the .one call to prevent double clicks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5944267/2028547 - better way to preventing multiple clicks on a button.